# Match words that begin with @

Tags: regex

I have next pattern `(^| )@[^@ ]+($|)`

And I have next string: `cdc@cd csd@ @as @refactoringGuru @ @as@refactoringGuru`.

So, in this case I match only one word - `@as` with space before the word.

But I need math also `@refactoringGuru`.

So, I need next output - `@as` `@refactoringGuru` without spaces before the words. And I Don't match `@as@refactoringGuru`

How I can do this?

Comment: `\b@\w+\b` should do…?

Comment: Your regex already does match `@refactoringGuru` https://regex101.com/r/B06B40/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)@` to match an `@` symbol at the beginning of a word:

```
(?<!\S)@\w+(?!\S)
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```
(?<!\S)   assert that what precedes is either whitespace or the start of the input
@         match an @ symbol
\w+       match one or more word characters
(?!\S)    assert that what follows is either whitespace or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(?<=^|\s)@\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6nD8v0/1/).

Comment: @as@refactoringGuru match too unfortunately